# How does google show this special iOS advert?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ads

Hi all sorry if this is repost. I really searched but can't find anything on it.

I always see this special ad when I use google services on my iphone or ipad. This little window animates out looking like a chat box. I can detect iOS device using user agent but how do I make the advert appear like google does? Specifically, try to open google maps.

I would like to use a window like this when users use iOS device to access my website. It is the most elegant way to tell iOS user about your app while not annoying them with some roadblock each time you try to access with iOS device.

Here is an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about exactly  - how to do this in HTML? How to get the rounded corners? How to link to an iPhone app?

Comment: And if it's about the "Install this app" part - is that not just a web  link? It doesn't *actually* install the Google Maps app, does it? (off to check) Edit: Indeed, on my iPad (iOS 5) it's just a web link, nothing fancy to it.

Comment: You can replicate this panel by loading a Google Maps URL into a UIWebView, for those that have not seen this before.

Comment: @Pekka - Didn't know you had an iPad. *stores info in brain* :-)

Comment: @Moshe it's really new. And I love it! With a bluetooth keyboard, it's the perfect writing and sketching tool.

Comment: @Pekka - (Pop into MSO tavern for a sec?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Javascript: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is your expectation, **When your page has access from any iOS device, you wanted to bring up that dialog in webpage**  Right?..
If That is the case then just retrieve the os info and make check there and do your presentation as you want.